# Spring integration imap cant read from sent and trash folder except inbox folder

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, jakarta-mail, spring-integration-dsl

I am new to spring integration and i need help. I can read and process mails from my inbox folder with the code below

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow imapMailFlow() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(imapUrl())
            .searchTermStrategy(new UnreadSearchTermStrategy())
            .userFlag("testSIUserFlag")
            .simpleContent(true)
            .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "false")),
                    e -> e.autoStartup(true)
            .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(100)))
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("imapInboxChannel")).get();
}
private String imapUrl() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return "imaps://" + URLEncoder.encode(mailHostService.getMailHost().getEmail(), "UTF-8") + ":"
            + mailHostService.getMailHost().getPassword() + "@" + mailHostService.getMailHost().getIncominghost()
            + ":" + mailHostService.getMailHost().getIncomingport() + "/" + "INBOX";
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "imapInboxChannel")
public MessageHandler processNewEmail() {
    MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) message.getPayload();
            processInboxMail.handleInboxMail(mimeMessage);
        }
    };
    return messageHandler;

}
```

But when i wrote the same code for sent folder and trash folder i cant read mails yet am not having any error. I have tested it with different mail clients, it only works with inbox folder

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow imapSentFlow() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Mail.imapInboundAdapter(imapSentUrl())
            //.searchTermStrategy(new UnreadSearchTermStrategy())
            .simpleContent(true)
            .javaMailProperties(p -> p.put("mail.debug", "false")),
                    e -> e.autoStartup(true)
            .poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(100)))
            .log("checking in the logs")
            .channel(MessageChannels.queue("imapSentChannel")).get();
}
private String imapSentUrl() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return "imaps://" + URLEncoder.encode(mailHostService.getMailHost().getEmail(), "UTF-8") + ":"
            + mailHostService.getMailHost().getPassword() + "@" + mailHostService.getMailHost().getIncominghost()
            + ":" + mailHostService.getMailHost().getIncomingport() + "/" + "INBOX.Sent";
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "imapSentChannel")
public MessageHandler processNewSentEmail() {
    MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) {
            System.out.println("Message Receive");
            MimeMessage mimeMessage = (MimeMessage) message.getPayload();
            processInboxMail.handleInboxMail(mimeMessage);
        }
    };
    return messageHandler;

}
```

Comment: I think the naming of the sent folder is wrong. It should be ```Sent``` and not ```INBOX.Sent```.

Comment: The naming is not wrong I have tested it before. I have tried your own before I got an error. With this line of code you can get all folders in the mailbox. folder[] folders = folders.getStore().getDefaultFolder().list(*);

Comment: You are right, sorry. Years ago I had the same problem. I'm not in the office now to check the code, but I remember the reason was the definition of  the DefaultSearchTermStrategy. https://github.com/bitwisekaizen/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-mail/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/mail/ImapMailReceiver.java#L192  Hope this helps!

Comment: But i have tried custom SearchTermStrategy yet it doesnt still work. As you can see i commentted on that line, //.searchTermStrategy(new UnreadSearchTermStrategy())

Comment: Is UnreadSearchTermStrategy really the right one? Commonly emails in Sent and Trash are flagged as ```SEEN```.

Comment: Wow. I just got to know this one now, thank you. Can i see a sample of customSearchTermStrategy for Sent and Trash?

Comment: You right. I changed my customSearchTermStrategy of Flags.Flag.SEEN to true, it started receiving sent mails, but the problem is it will keep receiving old mails. How can i handle it not to receive mail already proccess by the server

Answer (score 1):

Let's move the discussion out of the comments.

Ok, you have to keep in mind, what you want to do. I recommend to use an extra imap mailbox for processing emails with spring integration. If not, you have to check every time all `SEEN` flagged emails to decide, if it is relevant for processing or not. That could by a lot of emails!

Anyway.

If you want to have trackable email processing, I success to have two processes:

1. Process: Searching the Inbox for relevant emails and moving those email to a separate folder e.g. `to_process`.
2. Process: Proccessing all emails in `to_process`. If the processing was successful, move the mail into the folder `done`, otherwise into `process_failed`.

Hope, this is what you need. If not, you should describe your email processing a bit.

Comment: Mine is just simple. Download all (not some) inbox messages from the mailbox to a database and flagged them as read so it won't be downloaded again or when downloading check if the new message uuid is greater than the last message uuid to avoid duplicate messages. Move a copy of sent message to a Sent folder, all deleted messages should be moved to Trash folder for final delete.