# Receive mails from Inbox on startup with Integration Mail

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-integration

As already said in the title I'm looking for a way to receive mails with Integration Mail on Startup. Due to restrictions in the system I'm working in, the only way to get the mails is over the inbox and i should preferable only do it with integration mail. I know its possible with Javax.Mail, but its a lot of lines for just reading out the old mails on program start. I tired to do do it with a `SearchTermStrategy` with looking for already seen mails, but that ends up in a loop of reading old mails. Anybody knows a way to do it with integration mail?

I got a integration flow that constantly listens for mails, and i tried to do
do do one that reads out all the read mails, so i can keep track of them, the only problem with that is, that it checks for old mails via the SEEN Flag, and it cant differentiate between mails it already read out once that way, so it keeps reading out the same mails.

I also tried it with `ImapMailReceiver(url).setSearchTermStrategy(searchTermStrategy())`
with the strategy to get unseen mails, from trying with the debugger i saw there might be messages in the ImapMailReceiver, but I got no clue how to access them or if i can access those.
That's what I tried so far.

Comment: please show, in your question, wha tyou have tried so far.

Comment: Maybe my answer in this post could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322983/spring-integration-imap-cant-read-from-sent-and-trash-folder-except-inbox-folder/69343040#69343040

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz awfully not what i could do with it, I need to read through the mails on every program start, so if i try to get them "out the way" with moving them into another folder, i couldn't read them the next time i start the program

Comment: You will need an integration flow to read emails, so not sure what you currently have tried.

Comment: @M.Deinum but could i do a "one time" flow, that just reads all the OLD mails on startup of my program?

Comment: No. It will continue to poll the receiver. I don't really understand your usecase. Why would you want to retrieve all the emails (because that is basically what you are doing) at startup, it will be slow and become slower as the content grows

Answer (score 0):

See `MailReceivingMessageSource` and something like `OnlyOnceTrigger` to let Inbound Channel Adapter to work only once on startup. After only one execution it is not going to look into the source any more:

```
public class OnlyOnceTrigger implements Trigger {

    private final AtomicBoolean hasRun = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Override
    public Date nextExecutionTime(TriggerContext triggerContext) {
        return this.hasRun.getAndSet(true) ? null : new Date();
    }
    
}
```

I don't think the `ImapIdleChannelAdapter` is a good choice for this kind of tasks.